# How to use `traceparent` in OpenTelemetry for a PWA

Tags: logging, configuration, http-headers, progressive-web-apps, open-telemetry

## Context

I am looking into [OpenTelemetry](https://opentelemetry.io) and plan to use it in a completely **serverless PWA**. (https://web.replayer.app if you are interested)

## Problem

I am looking at the "Browser Example Application" in their [Getting Started in the Browser](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/browser/) docs. They refer to a "traceparent" HTTP header (as meta tag in the HTML file):

```
<meta
  name="traceparent"
  content="00-ab42124a3c573678d4d8b21ba52df3bf-d21f7bc17caa5aba-01"
/>
```

The idea, according to the documentation is that it's generated on the server:

```
<!--
  https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/
  Set the `traceparent` in the server's HTML template code. It should be
  dynamically generated server side to have the server's request trace Id,
  a parent span Id that was set on the server's request span, and the trace
  flags to indicate the server's sampling decision
  (01 = sampled, 00 = notsampled).
  '{version}-{traceId}-{spanId}-{sampleDecision}'
-->
```

I have read a bit into the [w3 docs about the traceparent header](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/#x3-2-traceparent-header), but **I can not see how I am supposed to use this in a PWA context**.

## Question

**How should a PWA client app (with only static server files) handle the `traceparent` header?**